# Cloning Checkboxes with different names

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, clone

For better understanding what I want to do, here is a screenshot

[image]

I want to be able to submit whether checkboxes are checked or not. For this I used the trick to have hidden input fields, because otherwise unchecked boxes are not submitted. What I want to do now is to give pairs (one hidden, one checkbox) the same name, but each pair a different name. I tried quite a bit with javascript and jQuery but could not figure out how to get this done. The "+" Button is for adding more Checkboxes, the "-" Button is for deleting them again.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function clone(button, objid)
{
    tmpvalue = document.test.elements['param[]'][1].value;

    document.test.elements['param[]'][1].value = '';

    var clone_me = document.getElementById(objid).firstChild.cloneNode(true);
    button.parentNode.insertBefore(clone_me, button);

    document.test.elements['param[]'][1].value = tmpvalue;
}

function remove_this(objLink)
{
    objLink.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(objLink.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="test" method="post" action="test2.php">
    <input name="param[0]" value="0" type="hidden">

    <div id="hidden" style="visibility:hidden; display:none">
    <div id="table"><table>
        <tr><td>
            <input name="param[]" type='hidden' value="0">
            Parameter: <input name="param[]" type="checkbox" value="1">
        </td>
        <td>
            <span style="margin-left:2em;"></span><input value="-" onclick="javascript:remove_this(this)" type="button">
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table></div>  
    </div>

    <div>
        <input  style="margin-top:2em;" value="+" onclick="javascript:clone(this, 'table');" type="button">
        <button type="submit" name="sent">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

So it would actually be nice to have some sort of counter like this:

```
<input name="param[i]" type='hidden' value="0">
Parameter: <input name="param[i]" type="checkbox" value="1">
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I can't load your image (my network blocks it) so with that said, in general, when you want to clone things, you should 1) make a template without ids like `<input name="field_">` in plain html, wrapped in a `display:none` element and then 2) use the $.clone() jQuery to create a copy, 3) update names/ids/labels with a function that also stores a counter.  There's some logic in this fiddle for that:  http://jsfiddle.net/briansol/5h4cM/1/   Then 4) actually append the clone to the DOM

Answer (score 0):

What about giving your checkboxes a class (for example "checkClass") and then scan all elements with this class using a jQuery? Like so..

```
// instead of $('button[type="submit"]') give your button an ID and use # selector
$('button[type="submit"]').click(function(){
    //lets get all checkboxes..
    $('.checkClass').each(function(){
        // get their checked status
        var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
        // ..and do whatever you need here..
    });
});
```

In terms of adding a new row on "plus" button click. Try considering the jquery "Append" method. Like so..

```
$('#plusButtonId').click(function(){
    var rowHtml = '<tr><td>Parameter: <input name="param[]" type="checkbox" class="checkClass" value="1"></td><td><input value="-" type="button" class="remButton"></td></tr>';
    $('#table').append(rowHtml);
});
```

..then use the ".remButton" selector and add a click event that will remove that tr element.

and last but not least - this is a great example why to start with AngularJS. It would be just one controller, a div with "ng-repeat" and a few methods. Try it ;)